# How to create a Link button programmatically?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I am trying to convert a series of buttons that will open webpages in the browser from an xml layout file into my Activity class (programmatically). How can I do this?

I have not been able to find questions that answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  /**
     * Open the specified URL on the device's browser
     *
     * @param context Current Context.
     * @param url     The url to display.
     */
    public static void openWebPage(@NonNull Context context, String url) {
        Uri webPage = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webPage);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Then in the onCreate of your Activity you get the button:

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
   ... // call the above method with the corresponding url
});
```

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Browser)

Answer (score 0):

The code....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 TextView textView;
 Spanned spannedText;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

 spannedText = Html.fromHtml("text with a link in it <br />" +
 "<a href='https://www.aol.com//'>aol.com</a>");

 textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 textView.setText(spannedText);
 }
}
```

XML TextView

```
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:layout_width="match_content"
 android:layout_height="match_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:text="LINK WILL SHOW UP HERE"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
 android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use webview in your android application.
[More about web view](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#AddingWebView)

Comment: No you dont. You can do it via code. Correct answer coming in a second.